# summing probability elements based on specific conditions from its associated list python

Tags: python, list, nested, sum

I have 4 lists and 2 of them have a one to one association, and Im using the other two to impose conditions. The A list is just a lists of things, while B is a list of 'probabilities' associated with each element in A. for example, this first element in A, [a, b] is associated with the first element in B, [0.12].

```
A=[[a, b], [c, f], [g, m], [h, j], [c, f], [g, m]]
B=[[0.12], [0.45], [0.98], [0.56], [0.34], [0.78]]
```

The third and fourth list (C, D) is as fallows,

```
C=[[c, f], [g, m]]
D=[[[a, b], [h, j]]
```

and Id like to iterate thru A to find all the common elements between A and C and put them into nested list inside E, and do the same for A and D (and put them inside another list in E). As well, sum up there associated probabilities into nested list in F. The code Ive worked out is as fallows,

```
E=[[ ], [ ]]
F=[[0], [0]]
for i in A:
    if i in C:
        E[0].append(i)
        F[0]= F[0]+ B[i]
for i in A:
    if i in D:
        E[1].append(i)
        F[1]= F[1]+B[i]
```

This gives out an error for "indices must be integers, not list". Im not sure what the problem is exactly, or if there is a better overall approach to the probability problem, but Id appreciate some help/advice.

Comment: is `A` `A=[[a, b], [c, f], [g, m], [h, j], [c, f], [g, m]]`  or `A=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'f'], ...]`  ??  does it work like you've shown in the question ??

Comment: and why is `D`  this - `D=[[['a', 'b'], ['h', 'j']]`  ??? 1 extra open-bracket is there in your question - syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to understand what you're trying to do after reading carefully.

You can use this for your task :

```
A=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'f'], ['g', 'm'], ['h', 'j'], ['c', 'f'], ['g', 'm']]
B=[[0.12], [0.45], [0.98], [0.56], [0.34], [0.78]]

C=[['c', 'f'], ['g', 'm']]
D=[['a', 'b'], ['h', 'j']]

# E=[[ ], [ ]]
# F=[[0], [0]]

common_in_a_c = {'lists_found': [], 'probabilities': []}
common_in_a_d = {'lists_found': [], 'probabilities': []}

for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] in C:
        common_in_a_c['lists_found'].append(A[i])
        common_in_a_c['probabilities'].append(B[i][0])
    if A[i] in D:
        common_in_a_d['lists_found'].append(A[i])
        common_in_a_d['probabilities'].append(B[i][0])

print(common_in_a_c)
print(common_in_a_d)
```

I have removed `E` and `F` which you had used . Made of of better approach to store what you desire - `common_in_a_c` and `common_in_a_d` are dictionaries - which will hold values of your interest.
Here I have stored entire list in `common_in_a_c['probabilities']` => on which you can perform `sum()` to get `sum of probabilities`

The problem in your code was the `B[i]` what you had used in the `loop` => `B[i]` won't work because `i` wasn't `index` but was `elements in A`  . So I have changed the logic to use `index-based-loop` .